# Compiladores para lenguajes?

Tags: linux, windows, compilador

Estoy trabajando con windows en las tareas de programacion . Y me surgio la duda, por lo que tengo entendido windows es software que se asemeja mas al usuario tradicional. Mi pregunta es ¿windows trae compiladores por defecto para los lenguajes de programacion?
Si Linux es de software libre.¿Trae los compiladores para todos los lenguajes de programacion?

Comment: windows no trae compiladores, pero no te preocupes, no toma demasiado tiempo y mucho menos es difícil poder instalarlos y agregarlos al path para poder ejecutar scripts, saludos

Comment: Igualmente, Linux como tal no trae todos los compiladores de todos los lenguajes del universo... Pero te Sports herramientas fáciles para instalarlos desde sus repositorios de aplicaciones

Comment: Generalmente ninguno trae compiladores por defecto. Son OS de uso general que se adaptan a lo que necesitas. Traen intérpretes para ciertos lenguajes de scripting, por ejemplo, Windows: VBScrip, PowerShell. Linux viene con Shell Script y casi siempre Python, algunos traen Perl. Lo demás tienes que instalarlo tu.

Comment: Un Sistema Operativo se encarga de gestionar la máquina y los usuarios; hoy en día al instalar el SO también se instalan aplicaciones adicionales pero usualmente no son parte del SO propiamente dicho (de la misma forma que una calculadora no lo es). Los compiladores son aplicaciones como cualquier otra, quien distribuya el SO puede incluirlas como aplicaciones adicionales o no pero no es especialmente relevante. Luego, como cualquier otra aplicación, puede haber aplicaciones que no puedan correr en determinados SOs.

Comment: Cuando instalas un SO, instalas programas *básicos* que *todos* usamos más o menos. Un compilador es un programa que ***muy pocos***usarán. Por qué vas a querer que tus posibles usuarios tengan que descargar cosas que nunca usarán?? Otra cosa es que descargues una distro de linux especifica para programación, que hay unas cuantas, y suelen traer bastantes cosas pre instaladas. Pero eso es ya un SO específicamente seleccionado para programar, nada genérico como Windows o Debian.

Answer (score 1):

**Realmente no, ni linux ni windows.**

El caso de **Linux** por su parte trae compiladores las distribuciones. para facilitar las instalaciones o el hecho de que linux se utiliza mas para entornos de trabajo y desarrollo por ende traen herramientas integradas en las distribuciones (la mayoría gratuitas). algunas de estas distribuciones requieren de una conexión a internet para descargar luego de la instalación dichas herramientas para pre-instalarlas.

En caso de **Windows**, esto que menciono en linux, no se aplica al 100%, para los de redmond, ellos en un inicio si querías usar windows para entornos de **trabajo** tenias que comprar la suite de desarrollo Visual Studio #### (año), luego la pasaron a gratuita la version de la comunidad para soporte de aplicaciones open source y al bum que ha tenido en los últimos días este tipo de software o paqueterías, en cuanto a la distribución los paquetes de entornos de trabajo y ofimática si traen compiladores para los lenguajes principales en los que se basa; office incluye soporte para macros programados en visual basic; y visual studio cada día ofrece compiladores para mas lenguajes de desarrollo que lo requieran; estas paqueterías de windows normalmente requiere de la instalación de alguna redistribución.

Con el conocimiento necesario y el soporte existente; cualquier sistema operativo puede llegar a albergar compiladores... pero dependerá 100% de la existencia y el soporte...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]